# Apache Reverse Proxy Unix Socket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, sockets, unix, proxy

I am trying to setup ProxyPass in Apache 2.4.7 using unix sockets to a puma server for a rails application. I keep receiving a 500 Internal Error. When I check the apache logs I receive this message:

**No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of     mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.**

This is my proxy config in apache

```
ProxyPass / unix:///home/rails/rp/tmp/sockets/puma.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
ProxyPassReverse / unix:///home/rails/rp/tmp/sockets/puma.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
```

If I setup a Proxy Pass on a regular tcp port like this, it works fine.

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9292
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9292
```

Any help is appreciated, let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: did you resolve this issue? I am stuck on same problem

Answer (score 3):

In general, there is some point for checking for reverse proxy an http server app over unix socket:

- Check if Apache already loaded required modules (proxy & http_proxy) using `apachectl -M` command
- Make sure that socket path is accessible for `www-data` user (it is default apache user)
- Check correctness of running app on unix socket using following command:
  `curl --unix-socket /var/www/app/socket/path -XGET http:/someMethod`
- Check that `ProxyPreserveHost On` already present in your virtual host file and set socket address correctly (as `unix:/var/www/path/to/your/socket`) and after pipe mark path correctly (as `|http://127.0.0.1/what/ever`)
- Make sure both `ProxyPassReverse` and `ProxyPass` is set correctly

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which proxy handler should handle sockets, so you could try loading them all then see which one does the job for you:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html

Note that you can also use SetHandler to specify the module you want to handle your connections

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I spent a while to find the solution on one of my old server.

When you have this mod_proxy error, it's because Apache doesn't recognize the proxy module to use behind the unix socket.

Assuming that you obviously already have :

`a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
service apache2 restart`

There's a good chance that your apache config file located at `/etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy_http.load` is empty

Add theses lines to this file :

```
# Depends: proxy
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

then
`service apache2 restart`