# How to proxy HTTP and Websockets from Apache to Gunicorn over unix sockets?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, mod-proxy, unix-socket, mod-proxy-wstunnel

My Setup already works over TCP with these two lines in my virtualhost:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/ws/.*$ ws://localhost:8000/
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
```

Now I want to use unix sockets. So I prepended `unix:$SOCKETPATH|` and removed the port:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/ws/.*$ unix:/run/myapp.sock|ws://localhost/
ProxyPass / unix:/run/myapp.sock|http://localhost/
```

It works for HTTP, but websocket connections fail. I tried variations of the right side in the websockets line, e.g.:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/ws/.*$ unix:/run/myapp.sock|ws:///
ProxyPassMatch ^/ws/.*$ unix:/run/myapp.sock|ws://
```

Besides getting it to work, I'd like to understand why there is the part after the pipe (|) needed anyways? After all, Apache should only need to know the unix socket path, shouldn't it? The [Apache documentation on ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) does not explain this.

These similar questions did not help:

- [Apache Reverse Proxy Unix Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527427/apache-reverse-proxy-unix-socket)
- [How to use Apache as a reverse-proxy for WebSockets with Undertow as the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901082/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-websockets-with-undertow-as-the-server)

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the Debian Apache packets from 2.4.38-3+deb10u4 (stable) to 2.4.46-4~bpo10+1 (backports) and now it works. The Apache changelog mentions multiple changes to websockets. I suppose this change might have been the problem:

```
mod_proxy_wstunnel: Leave Upgrade requests handling to mod_proxy_http,
allowing for (non-)Upgrade negotiation with the origin server.
```